# Send activation code to GSM Mobile

Tags: joomla1.5

i want to this:

When a new user want ta register to my site, he/she must enter GSM number on registration form

and activation code sent with a SMS message and e-mail.

he/she must enter SMS activation code and e-mail activation code for complete joomla new user register process.

Is this possible? Can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

yes, But you have to think a lot about integration your implementation with Joomla.

You have 2 approaches to send SMS messages.

**1. Using a GSM modem**

Here you will need dedicated hardware to do this. You will need a GSM modem + A dedicated server/machine. You have to write to the serial port using appropriate language and use AT commands to send sms messages. Here the advantage is everything is yours so you have total control over everything. You will be able to find a cheap mobile service provider for this.

**2. Using an SMS Gateway**
Based on your requirement of integrating this with Joomla, this might be the easy approach. In this way you have to send http, https request to a certain URL with the message information and authentication details. The gateway will handle the rest. Alternatively you can choose SMTP as gateway protocol and reuse your email implementation. When you send an email to a certain preconfigured address it will generate an SMS with contents of the email message.

[Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/) is an example for such service providers.

Comment: Yes , I have already a SMS gateway , visit :http://www.softlinkweb.com ,I wanted to send the SMS to the registration time . check out my registration form http://www.softlinkweb.com/index.php/component/user/?task=register . Now the real problem , Where i should add the real API code ?? . Which file i have to edit ? How i will get all information such as , Mobile no , tokenlink , uername .